# HyperV management through Windows 8

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, windows-8, hyper-v-server-2012

Consider the following setup:

- 1 Hypervisor
- 3 Clients (Server 2012 with AD, Server 2012, Windows 8).

Now we can remote desktop into the Hypervisor and manage the VMs with the manager.
This also works from the Server 2012 (I installed the manager there).

But it doesn't work from the Windows 8 machine.
By that I mean that I get that I am unauthorized to connect to the HyperV manager.

All machines are in the same domain.

Am I forgetting something?

I followed [this long page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794756%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

But I find it so weird that it works for the same user on Windows Server 2012, but not on Windows 8.

Comment: "doesn't work" - feel like elaborating or do we need to put on our mind-reader caps?

Comment: Yeah. I run tons of 2012 servers and win8 clients and never had a problem remoting into 2012 server from a win8 machine. Not once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the RSAT tools for Windows 8, mainly the Server Management tools - there's a known issue with them not installing properly until you install the en-US language pack. Most Windows 8 machines only have en-GB, and the RSAT tools will not work with this language pack.(powershell command = Add-WindowsPackage -PackagePath .\langpacks\en-us\lp.cab -Online)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an Administrative-level account that also has local admin rights to the Windows 8 PC, you might check your firewall settings and NLA (network location awareness) settings on the Windows 8 PC to ensure they are not blocking access to the Hypervisor.